# serial port settings for scale model 240878

Tags: serial-port

Has anyone ever have configured the serial port settings for a globalindustrial scale model 240878?

I have tried some many configuration already using `BC-Wedge` but can't get the right value from the scale.

The scale's manual is useless, nothing in the web about this so far.

I have done this with other scales and I was able to read the weight without any issue.

These are the parameters I need for this model:

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort(cbxPorts.Text);                    
_serialPort.BaudRate =                     
_serialPort.Parity =                     
_serialPort.DataBits =                   
_serialPort.StopBits =                     
_serialPort.Handshake =
```

Comment: What have you tried? And can you tell if the scale is sending anything at all? Did you try opening up a terminal program (I'm fond of RealTerm, but there are many) and see if you see anything from the scale?

Comment: Have you tried asking the manfacturer? http://www.globalindustrial.com/contactUs. They also have live chat ...

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, that was one of the first things I did, they don't know, they will contact the vendor :|

Comment: @MichaelKohne I was able to get something from the scale, but just junk, in my previous experience with OHAUS scale, this is because of serial port configurations, but the thing is that OHAUS has a detailed info about that, so I was able to get the right reading in those, not the same thing with this scale. I've been play around with different configurations using `BC-Wedge` but always junk, that's why I'm asking to see if someone has had luck with this particular scale.

Comment: @Somebody - wait, you mean the manufacturer has to ask the guys who sell it for them how the damn thing works? Are you in a position where you can refuse to work with this equipment? Because this doesn't sound like a good start.

Comment: @Somebody - The next thing I'd try is opening up a terminal program and starting with the settings where you got junk, and then walk through all the baud rates it offers and see what you find.

Comment: @MichaelKohne is in the other way around, according to globalinsdustrial guys, they are the sellers, so they don't know how the thing works. I believe I'll never get a response from the vendor. I've been trying different configurations but there are to many available. Nothing so far, I'll be returning those cheapy scales.

Comment: @Somebody - Ahh, I see. Too bad, but it may be that they simply DON'T work. Good luck on getting something else to go.